# Override standard CSS for hidden input tags

Tags: html, css

For HTML tags such as `<input type="hidden">` when I look at the browser's standard CSS, I see:

```
input[type="hidden" i] {
    display: none; 
}
```

So I added this to my CSS:

```
input[type="hidden" i] {
    display: block !important; 
}
```

And for HTML I have `<input name=countrycode type=hidden value=US>`

When I open up the developer tools I can see that the old `display:none` is ignored, however, the field never shows up in the page and is still hidden!

Why doesn't  the browser follow my CSS rules, is there another way to force it to do so?  If I add `width: 200;height:200;background: black` this should make it appear in the page, right?

The reason I want to do this is because I have a lot of hidden inputs in many pages that now I want them to be visible (to get input from user) so I decided to do it fast with CSS. I know this can be easily done with JavaScript, but just curious why CSS is not working or maybe it will work on other browsers but not Google Chrome?

Comment: You can not get an input field of type=hidden to accept user input using CSS. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#hidden-state-(type=hidden): _"The input element represents a value that is not intended to be examined or manipulated by the user."_

Comment: "I know this can be easily done with JavaScript" with this I meant that I would just change the value of `type` attribute.

Comment: Why doesn't the browser follow my CSS rules? If I add `width: 200;height:200;background: black` , this should make it appear in the page, right?

Comment: _"Why doesn't the browser follow my CSS rules?"_ - because it follows what I just quoted from the HTML5 spec; if a browser wants to apply this specification correctly, that means it must not follow any of your attempts to overrule this fundamental property of a hidden input element.

Comment: To spare the time of anyone else this might occur to, changing the value of `visibility` and `appearance` (or any other CSS) doesn't work either: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance

Comment: Also, if you continue with the spec CBroe linked to, it states that the browser *can't* give an input with type hidden a width or a height.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your `input[type=hidden]` is hidden, is because it doesn't have a control type to show the user it's value, so your `display: block;` should work, but the browser'll have nothing to render. Your hidden input could be a checkbox, a text field or a number.

More info: https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input

Comment: The easiest way would be to change the attribute using JavaScript for all hidden inputs which I have already done, My question is about why the browser doesn't follow my CSS rules.

Comment: The problem is that what you're doing isn't according to the W3C Standard. There's no way defined to show a hidden type. Your block'll be empty

Answer (score 0):

You should give that input an id="countrycode" and just use javascript to set the value of type attribute from "hiden" to "text" like this:

```
document.getElementById("countrycode").setAttribute("type", "text");
```

OR if you prefer to use the name attribute, then do this:

```
document.getElementByName("countrycode").setAttribute("type", "text");
```

Voila!